# Спойлер разворачивается плавно, сворачивается без анимации - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, joomla

Собственно проблема описана в названии вопроса. Есть кнопка и код:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hide-me">Показать фильтры</button>
<div id="hide-me" class="collapse">
...
</div>
```

Бутстрап подключен полностью. Платформа - Joomla 3. Шаблон самописный. Все работает, но почему то именно **сворачивание** спойлера происходит без эластик-анимации. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Нужно увидеть проблему, чтобы подумать над решением. Дайте ссылку на страницу или соберите [работающий пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в том, что Joomla загружает автоматически свои библиотеки Mootools, jQuery, Bootstrap. Если с помощью плагина это отключить (или захардкодить (не рекомендуется, т.к. при обновлении слетит) в ) - всё станет работать корректно.

Может кому-нибудь пригодится